# Ubuntu 12.04 - how to restart USB interfaces?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb, package-management, camera

How can I restart the USB Interfaces in Ubuntu 12.04 like in FreeBSD? Is there any packages or source codes for Ubuntu?

```
 usbconfig -u 1 -a 2 suspend
       usbconfig -u 1 -a 2 resume
       usbconfig -u 1 -a 2 power_off
       usbconfig -u 1 -a 2 power_save
       usbconfig -u 1 -a 2 power_on

# Find usb devices
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/product 
EHCI Host Controller
EHCI Host Controller
xHCI Host Controller
xHCI Host Controller

# disable external wake-up; do this only once
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup 
echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level       # turn on
echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level  # turn off


[29001.554561] WARNING! power/level is deprecated; use power/control instead
```

Answer (score 0):

As of the 2.6.35 kernel, the `level` file is **depreciated** and now replaced by `control`.

The `auto` state is the normal state in which the kernel is allowed to autosuspend and autoresume the device.
In kernels up to 2.6.32, one could also specify `suspend`, meaning that the device should remain suspended and autoresume was not allowed. This setting is **no longer supported.**

More details can be found in the current [Power management for USB](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt) kernel documentation.